Plaid Transaction Sync, Access Token Rotation and Cursor Position
I am implementing/using Plaid's Transaction product. And I have a question regarding the API interface.
If my access token for an institution is regenerated / rotated, will the cursor location of the previous access token still be valid for the new access token for the same account of the same institution?
I am asking this because, during implementation, in sandbox mode, I encountered an error where Plaid had invalidated an access token and asked to reauthenticate the token.
See more details regarding the error through these links:

ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED - Item has expired credentials or consent
https://plaid.com/docs/errors/

Plaid Transaction API doc.:
https://plaid.com/docs/api/products/transactions/#transactionssync


Thanks!

Yes, it will still be valid. Going through update mode does not impact the cursor.

Thank for the response!

When an access-token expires, error ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED: do we renew the same access token or we renew the item expiration date by getting a new access token?

If we have to renew / revalidate the same access token, how to do this?

// You do not need to repeat the /item/public_token/exchange
// process when a user uses Link in update mode.
// The Item's access_token has not changed.

Doc about update mode: https://plaid.com/docs/link/update-mode/
